Read weight from a weighing scale: is it possibile to sum 2 consecutive weighings?
I have an issue with reading the weight from a weighing scale.
My Main simply connects via tcp to a remote host and reads the stream to catch the weight.
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
  TcpClient tcpClient = Connect.ConnectionSetup(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), portNumber);
  NetworkStream netStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

  while (true)
  {
   var receivedString = String.Empty;
   var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");

   var response = Response.Read(netStream, receivedString);
   Console.WriteLine($"{timestamp} - {response}");
                
   Thread.Sleep(500);
   }
}

The Read method writes the command READ and reads from the stream to return the weight as a string. It is built like this
private static string command = "READ\r\n";

public static string Read(NetworkStream netStream, string receivedString)
{
  byte[] commandBuffer;
  byte[] readingBuffer;

  commandBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(command);
  netStream.Write(commandBuffer, 0, commandBuffer.Length);

  if (netStream.DataAvailable)
  {
   readingBuffer = new byte[256];
   var response = netStream.Read(readingBuffer, 0, readingBuffer.Length);
   receivedString += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readingBuffer, 0, response);
  }
  return receivedString;
}

Reading a single weighing was simple, but how can i do to read a double weighing in order to sum the two weights?
Knowing that the string received from the scale is built like this one:
ST,NT,   0,kg
I tried this DoubleWeighing method to catch the total weight from the two weighings but it doesn't work. This method makes two readings: catches the first response and extracts the weight, catches the second and does the same. If the time difference between the two is less than 60 seconds it means there has been a second weighing. So it sums the two weights and replaces the weight in the second response with the new weight to return the string. If there hasn't been a double weighing than it returns simply the first response.
public static string DoubleWeighing (NetworkStream netStream, string receivedString)
{
 var firstResponse = Read(netStream, receivedString).Trim();
 string[] splittedFirstResponse = firstResponse.Split(','); 
 var firstWeight = Convert.ToDouble(splittedFirstResponse[2]);
 DateTime firstWeightTime = DateTime.Now;
            
 var secondResponse = Read(netStream, receivedString).Trim();
 string[] splittedSecondResponse = secondResponse.Split(','); 
 var secondWeight = Convert.ToDouble(splittedSecondResponse[2]);
 DateTime secondWeightTime = DateTime.Now;

 TimeSpan timeDifference = secondWeightTime - firstWeightTime;

 if (secondWeight != firstWeight && secondWeight != 0 && timeDifference.TotalSeconds <= 60)
 {
  var totalWeight = firstWeight + secondWeight;
  string output = secondResponse.Replace(splittedSecondResponse[2], Convert.ToString(totalWeight));
  return output;
 }
 else
 {
  return firstResponse;
 }

}

This returns Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
Am I wrong with this way to think of a double weighing? There is a simplier way that can work?

Sounds like XY problem. What is double weighing exactly?

@Sinatr Double weighing means two consecutive weighings. For example: i receive a response from the weighing scale that says ST,NT,   100,kg. After less than 60 seconds i receive another ST,NT,   120,kg. I want to take the two weights and sum them to return the total.

Without any tricks? Just two readings? Make a method to read one weight and ... call it twice and sum values?

Yes, that's it.

This code is assuming that you a) always read the complete string (spoiler: you cannot rely on that) and b) that the string received is of the expected format. You actually need to validate that each of those assumptions are actually met. That includes that after the split you first make sure there is a [2]. Guess what happens if there isn't ... then you are trying to access with an index that is outside the bounds of the array.

I actually already tested this code in a major project and it works because i want to receive always the complete string and the string it's of the format i posted in the questions or an error string coming from the weighing scale.

It works fine to log all the responses i receive, but i need to do a double weighing. I know that there is an out of bounds exception because initially this method takes the empty string. For the logging it's actually fine if i receive an empty response because it means i'm not reading anything, but when it comes to test the double weighing and extract the weight it works obviously only  if he response is not null.

"and it works" - out of sheer luck, not because of craftsmanship. It's what we call "nice-weather-code". Matter of fact is: here you have a IndexOutOfBounds. One way you can have that is if the string you are working on is not actually looking like the string you expect. And if so, then it won't be just because you want it to.

If you know you can have empty responses, then you basically just need to keep reading until you have two vaild readings. That should be it. But that includes that you are able to detect invalid readings.

"Are you even listening to me? It works for the single weighing" - And I am telling you : It is not "working" - at least not reliably.

That's the problem, i didn't want to rely on a regex to valid the reading, but maybe it's the only option.

Well, there is more than one way to skin a cat. You could start by checking if the split result has the expected count of items for example. And if not, you could repeat the attempt to read ...

Ok i got what you understood. I'm NOT using this DubleWeighing method to read the single weighing. i just use the Read method for that, and tht's why it works for a single weighing.

Then maybe it's as easy as just using the SingleWeighing Method twice instead of the lower level (I guess) "Read" ?

Yes the split has the expected result if i put in it a valid response. The problem has i said is the empty string.

I don't use any SingleWeighing method, i just use Read to read the weight
